# Mysql in Nginx takes over 100% CPU

Tags: nginx, mysql, php, ubuntu-18.04, laravel

I have a Laravel application running on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and MySql 5.7.
Sometimes, it is very slow.
I have checked with "top" command and this is the result:

[image]

Some times %cpu raises over 140% for mysqld command, and i presume this is the reason for very slow site (I thhink this is the cause).

I have root access to SSH, if someone needs more informations (I'm new with Linux/nginx).

What should i do to solve the problem?

Comment: High CPU (or Load Average) almost always means a slow query -- Find it and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Your system has 16GB of RAM and your MySQL instance uses only 409MB and a few hundreds of MB for php-fpm and system processes. It seems that 90% of your system resources are underutilized.

Comment: First try to enable  slow_query_log in my.cnf to check which query is taking a lot of time and see if you can optimize it.  Also you might check the output from SHOW VARIABLES and SHOW STATUS and raise the memory limits for mysql - innodb_buffer_pool_size and key_buffer_size variables will be a good start depending on your storage engine. The "mysqladmin extended-status" command can also be used to see MySQL status details.

Comment: @AlexD thank you for your response. How can I increase MySQL instance memory, to optimize the system that have 90% of resources underutilized?

Comment: @pasluc74669 MySQL tuning questions are more suitable for dba.stackexchange.com. In your case setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 50-75% of your RAM should give the most performance improvement (but only if you are using InnoDB).

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Your URL in your profile is not available today. You may want to update your profile.  Welcome to serverfault.